# NullPointerException в цикле while

Tags: java, null

Есть код, в котором в цикле падает ошибка `NullPointerException` вот в этом месте:

```java
while (!((line = reader.readLine()).equals(null)))
```

Но если заменить его, допустим, на:

```java
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
```

То всё работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело?

```java
public class Solution {
    public static List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Statics.FILE_NAME));
            String line;

            while (!((line = reader.readLine()).equals(null))) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(lines);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вызывать нестатический метод (в данном случае `equals`) можно только у существующего объекта. Если ссылка (в данном случае `line`) указывает на null, то при попытке вызвать через неё метод получается NPE.

Опретор `!=` просто проверяет указывает ли ссылка на `null`,  не пытаясь обращаться ни к каким методам. Поэтому и исключения не генерируется.

Answer (score 0):

Дважды бессмысленная команда:

```java
null.equals(null)
```

Метод `equals` можно выполнить только на объекте (!!), а не на `null` вместо него. Далее передача в него параметра `null` опять не имеет смысла, т. к. метод уже вызван.

---

См. [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)